# ¿Como puedo hacer una llamada a una funcion cuando el cliente selecciona un item de una lista?

Tags: javascript, html, c#

Estoy cargando los datos de un cliente mediante una funcion de js con el evento de .click, pero no funciona como espero ya que el realizar este click me carga los datos por cada click que le hago a la lista haciendo que se demore mas en mostrarme los datos en la lista de contacto del cliente especifico.
Que otro tipo de evento o función podría usar en vez de .click?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo HTML de la tabla

```
<div class="content-wrapper">

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<section class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Ingreso de Cotización</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="@Url.Content("~/Home")">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Cotización</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="content">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-12">

                <div class="card-indigo">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Cotización</h3>

                        <div class="card-tools">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Cotizacion", new { })" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Volver <i class="fas fa-backward"></i></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="card card-green">
                                        <div class="card-header">
                                            <h3 class="card-title">Datos</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>Numero de Cotización</label>
                                                        @Html.TextBox("Numero", Model.GenerarNumero(), new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtNumero", ReadOnly = true })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessage("Numero")
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>Fecha</label>
                                                        @Html.TextBox("Fecha", Model.FechaHoy(), new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtFecha", ReadOnly = true })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessage("Fecha")
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>Cliente</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("ClienteSAP", Model.CargaCliente(), new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtClienteSAP" })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessage("ClienteSAP")
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>Contacto</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("NotasPedido", new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtContacto" })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessage("NotasPedido")
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="card card-lightblue">
                                        <div class="card-header">
                                            <h3 class="card-title">Cliente</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Nombre</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Nombre_Cliente", Model.Nombre, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtNombre", ReadOnly = true })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Nombre_Cliente")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Rut</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Identificador", Model.Rut, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtRut", ReadOnly = true })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Identificador")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                                @Html.TextBox("CodigoSAP_Cliente", Model.CodigoSAP_Cliente, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtCodigoSAP", ReadOnly = true, style = " display:none" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("CodigoSAP_Cliente")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Forma de Pago</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("FormaPago", Model.FormaPago, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtFormaPago", ReadOnly = true })
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Nombre_Pago", Model.Nombre_Pago, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "500", id = "txtNombrePago", style = " display:none" })
                                                                @Html.TextBox("CodigoSAP_Pago", Model.CodigoSAP_Pago, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "500", id = "txtCodigoPago", style = " display:none" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("IdFormaPago")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                           
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-center">
                            @*<button class="btn btn-info text-center" id="btnEnviar">Guardar Pedido</button>*@
                            <input type="button" value="Guardar Cotización" class="btn btn-info text-center" id="btnEnviar" style="margin:auto">
                            @*<input type="button" value="Test" class="btn btn-info text-center" id="btnFuncion" style="margin:auto" >*@
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</div>
```

El script que estoy usando es este donde obtengo los datos del cliente y una vez obtenidos puedo cargar los datos en la lista de contacto

```
<script>
$('#txtClienteSAP').click(function () {
    var nombre = $('#txtClienteSAP').val();

    var params = {
        nombre: nombre
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Cotizacion/CargaCliente',
        data: params,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#txtRut").val(result.rut);
            $("#txtCodigoSAP").val(result.codigo);
            $("#txtNombre").val(result.cliente);
            $("#txtFormaPago").val(result.nombrePago);
            $("#txtCodigoPago").val(result.codigoPago);
            $("#txtNombrePago").val(result.nombrePago);
            $("#txtCredito").val(result.creditLimit);
            $("#txtCreditoComp").val(result.creditoComprometido);
            $("#txtContacto").val(result.contactoEmpleado);

            console.log(result.contactoEmpleado);
            //var credit = $("#txtCredito").val();
            //var creditComp = $("#txtCreditoComp").val();

            //var disponible = credit - creditComp;

            //$("#txtCreditoDisp").val(disponible);

            CargaCotizacion();
         


            function CargaCotizacion() {
                let nombre = $("#txtCodigoSAP").val();
                let url = `/Cotizacion/CargaContacto?nombre=${nombre}`;

                SetCargando($("#txtContacto"))

                if (nombre.length === 0) {
                    DeleteCargaCotizacion();
                    return;
                }

                $.getJSON(url)
                    .done(function (result) {
                        //console.log(result);
                        let options = [];

                        if (result.length == 0) {
                            alert("El cliente no posee cotizaciones");
                            return;
                        }

                        options.push('<option value="">(Seleccione Contacto)</option>');

                        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            options.push(`<option id="idCotizacionValor" value="${result[i]}">${result[i]}</option>`)
                        }
                        console.log('options', options);
                        $("#txtContacto").html(options.join(''));



                    })
                    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    })
            }



            function DeleteCargaCotizacion() {
                $("#txtContacto option").remove();
                let options = [];
                options.push('<option value="">(Seleccione cotización)</option>');
                $("#txtContacto").html(options.join(''));

            }

            function SetCargando(element) {
                var options = [];
                options.push('<option value="', '', '">', 'Cargando...', '</option>');
                element.html(options.join(''));
            }


        },
    });
})
</script>
```

Lo que espero es que al seleccionar el cliente se carguen los datos tanto del cliente como los datos del contacto del cliente.

Comment: ¿Es necesario que tengas las funciones dentro del success? ¿y a que corresponde #txtClienteSAP?  ¿a un botón?

Comment: #txtClienteSAP es el nombre de la lista de clientes que obtengo de sap, y la funcion la estoy ejecutando cuando selecciono unos de los clientes, pero cada click que hago me carga la funcion y lo que quiero es que al seleccionar se cargue la funcion

Comment: Pues delimita el click usando `event.target` identificando el elemento que ha sido pulsado. Si pusieras el HTML de esa tabla en la pregunta y me indicarás que elemento para ti es "seleccionar un cliente" te indicaria como hacerlo, pero a ciegas poco más se te puede ayudar.

Comment: voy a modificar la pregunta y agregare el html para que veas la tabla